# How to create multiple user library lists filter in VS Code for IBM i development

Tags: visual-studio-code, ibm-midrange, rpgle

we work in multiple envts(different library list) in AS400/IBMi system.
Each envt has its own set of default libraries on same IBM i system.

We are trying to utilize VS code for IBMi development and looking for a easy way to switch to different library lists when working/compiling on programs from VS code.

Eg -
Project 1 - Need Lib list with 5 libraries
Project 2 - Need Lib list with 10 libraries

Trying to figure out a way to create multiple user library lists so that we can switch library lists by a click depending on which envt is being used for development.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current LIBL to a profile
[image]

Then once you have a profile, you can make changes and save it to another profile.

[image]

Changing LIBL is then just a matter of activating the correct profile.